# Error 429: rateLimitExceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

When adding data continuously to the file on GCS buckets mounted from the VM instance, the following error occurred.

```
info info Aug 20 13:20:07 myserver gcsfuse gcsfuse: fuse: 2018/08/20 13:20:07.807693 *fuseops.FlushFileOp error: FileInode.Sync: SyncObject: Create: CreateObject: googleapi: Error 429: The total number of changes to the object myproject/mydir/WORK.csv exceeds the rate limit. Please reduce the rate of create, update, and delete requests., rateLimitExceeded
```

We have an option to make the number of requests unlimited.

```
ExecStart=/bin/gcsfuse -o allow_other -file-mode=777 -dir-mode=777 --limit-ops-per-sec -1 --only-dir mydir/ --foreground myproject /etc/mount
```

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting this error due to trying to upload the object more than 1 time x second. The flag [`--limit-ops-per-sec`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse#rate-limiting) is the rate of requests, and it looks like you exceeded it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I think the same thing.
Since "-1" is specified for the flag "- limit - ops - per - sec", recognition is unlimited.
However, an error indicating that the limit has been exceeded has come up.